# Как добавить записи через WPF в базу данных SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

пишу проект связанный с базой данных, возник вопрос добавления новой записи в бд. Вывод производится в дата грид из таблицы. [image: Форма вывода в дата грид]

[image: Форма добавления студента]

Хотелось бы узнать, как через textbox-(Ы) реализовать добавление в базу данных и вообще возможно ли такое?

Comment: При нажатии кнопки "Добавить" делаете при помощи команды, ну или события Click действие добавления в базу, где собираете все данные с текстбоксов. Ведь элементарная задача и я сильно удивлен подобному вопросу, а это значит, что вы даже не пробовали сделать сами, чего уж от нас хотите, ответ на `возможно ли такое?` - да. возможно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
 Я разобрался как добавлять одно поле, а как добавить несколько?


`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Students (First_Name_Students)values(@nm)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", Name.Text);`

Answer (score 1):

Так же чтобы добавить несколько полей, делаем так:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Students (First_Name_Students,Last_Name_Students,Mid_Name_Students,Address_Students,Course_Students)values(@nm,@ln,@mn,@ad,@co)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", Name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", LastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mn", MidName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", Address.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@co", Course.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Students (First_Name_Students)values(@nm)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", Name.Text);
```